# g++ warning sprintf may be writing to zero length string that has been malloc'd

Tags: c

Am getting a compiler warning, that says am writing into string that might be 0 when string has been successfully malloc'd

Am formatting a date as YYYY-MM-DD for printing, where the calling routine needs to free the return which may be a nullptr.

Code is something like:

```
char* formatDate(const time_t dateIn){

//Allocate memory for the new date
char *formattedDate = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * 11);

if (formattedDate != nullptr) {
    
    memset(formattedDate, '\0', 11);
    
    //Sanity check the input
    if (dateIn == LONG_MAX){
        strncpy(formattedDate, "MAX DATE", 10);
        return formattedDate;
    }
    
    struct tm *dateInStruct = gmtime(&dateIn);  //no need to free this memory
    sprintf(formattedDate, "%4i%1c%02i%1c%02i", (dateInStruct->tm_year + 1900), '-', (dateInStruct->tm_mon + 1), '-', dateInStruct->tm_mday);
    //sprintf(formattedDate, "%4i%c%02i%c%02i", (dateInStruct->tm_year + 1900), '-', (dateInStruct->tm_mon + 1), '-', dateInStruct->tm_mday); //Also gives warning
    //sprintf(formattedDate, "%4i-%02i-%02i", (dateInStruct->tm_year + 1900), (dateInStruct->tm_mon + 1), dateInStruct->tm_mday); //Also gives warning about - as a directive
    
}

return formattedDate;
}
```

g++ with -Wall gives

```
warning: ‘%1c’ directive writing 1 byte into a region of size between 0 and 7 [-Wformat-overflow=]
  576 |                 sprintf(formattedDate, "%4i%1c%02i%1c%02i", (dateInStruct->tm_year + 1900), '-', (dateInStruct->tm_mon + 1), '-', dateInStruct->tm_mday);
      |                                            ^~~
note: directive argument in the range [-2147483647, 2147483647]
  576 |                 sprintf(formattedDate, "%4i%1c%02i%1c%02i", (dateInStruct->tm_year + 1900), '-', (dateInStruct->tm_mon + 1), '-', dateInStruct->tm_mday);
      |                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
note: ‘sprintf’ output between 11 and 36 bytes into a destination of size 11
  576 |                 sprintf(formattedDate, "%4i%1c%02i%1c%02i", (dateInStruct->tm_year + 1900), '-', (dateInStruct->tm_mon + 1), '-', dateInStruct->tm_mday);
      |                 ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

To help with my OCD, what's the expected handling approach?

g++ 12.3.0

Comment: There's no need to specify `%1c`. Just use `%c`... Further:, `%02d` means the _minimum_ width of 2 digits... You could try `%02.2d` to specify the field will be limited to 2 digits. (I don't know if this would work.) Aside `sizeof(char)` is defined to be `1` so is useless. And, casting the returned pointer from `malloc()` is legal, but not advisable... Look at `strftime()`

Comment: Thanks - your comment that %02 is a minimum helped. Could not get 2.2 to work, but strftime() worked.

Comment: Suggestion: Rather than counting up to some number, use _compile time_ initialisation to let the compiler do the work: `char *dtStr = malloc( 4 + 1 + 2 + 1 + 2 + (1) );` It's a bit of a mouthful, but a reader can verify accounting for `YYYY-MM-DD\0"` Whereas `11` is a magic number that may easily be off-by-one (just like one of the answers below...)

Comment: A little bit pedantic, but it looks like you're using a C++ compiler to compile C code. While it's probably irrelevant in this specific case, it may complicate matters.

Comment: The format would be simpler to read if you used `%04d-%02d-%02d"` — unless you use a variable for the delimiters (so you can choose between `-` and `/` at runtime, for example), there is no need to use `%1c` and an extra argument.  Using `%i` makes sense with `scanf()` — it will read decimal, hexadecimal or ocatl.  However, with dates, using `%i` for input leads to confusion because `08` and ``09` are read as zeroes because neither `8` nor `9` is a valid octal digit.  With `printf()`, `%i` is synonymous with `%d`.  You can use `(tm->tm_year + 1900) %10000` to limit the range of values.

Answer (score 2):

The warning is ultimately about writing out of bounds. `-2147483647` is 11 `char`s alone and you've allocated allocated 11 bytes so that's a potential write out of bounds right there. Add to that the rest you aim to add do the allocated buffer.

Your compiler does not know if you intend to run the program in the year -2147483647 or not. If you can provide proof to the compiler that the year will be at most 4 `char`s (modulus), it won't complain about that part. Do the same for any other numbers you do not really have control over.

Answer (score 2):

The string that could potentially be written to `formattedDate` can be larger than the space you've allocated for it, as mentioned in the other answer.

The way to address this is to allocate exactly the space you need.  This can be done by first calling `snprintf` instead of `sprintf` with NULL for the first argument and 0 for the second.  This will return the number of bytes that would be written to.  Then expand the buffer to that size (plus 1 for the terminating null byte) and call `snprintf` again.

```
int len = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%4i%1c%02i%1c%02i", 
             (dateInStruct->tm_year + 1900), '-', 
             (dateInStruct->tm_mon + 1), '-', dateInStruct->tm_mday);
formattedDate = (char*) realloc(formattedDate, sizeof(char) * len + 1);
snprintf(formattedDate, len+1, "%4i%1c%02i%1c%02i", 
             (dateInStruct->tm_year + 1900), '-', 
             (dateInStruct->tm_mon + 1), '-', dateInStruct->tm_mday);
```

An even better way to do this is to just use `strftime`, which is specifically built for formatting date/time strings and also allows you to specify a max size:

```
strftime(formattedDate, 11, "%Y-%m-%d", dateInStruct);
```

Comment: thanks - settled on: strftime(formattedDate, 11, "%F", dateInStruct);